Is it possible to construct a mealy/moore deterministic machine which gives an output (say x) for termination type languages?
As far as I know, Mealy and Moore machine are transducing machines and not language acceptors. So, can a Mealy/Moore machine, satisfying their very definitions, be made for languages which deal with termination types?
Here's a quick problem link to get a picture of what I am saying: https://www.javatpoint.com/automata-mealy-machine#:~:text=The%20mealy%20machine%20will%20be%3A

Design a mealy machine that scans sequence of input of 0 and 1 and
generates output 'A' if the input string terminates in 00, output 'B'
if the string terminates in 11, and output 'C' otherwise.


I don't understand what is meant by "languages which deal with termination types".

I meant it in a naive way to deal with strings which are of the type "ends with k".

Please [edit] your question to clarify your meaning.  We prefer that you revise your question so it is self-contained and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and so that new readers can understand what is being asked without having to read the comments.
